# How to control a flash film with JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

i have a project where i have a movie.swf (AS2) and some buttons with js/jQuery in the html part. Now i want the buttons to control the flash. For Example pressing Button1 would do a gotoAndPlay(1) and Button2 gotoAndPlay(150) Button3 gotoAndStop(450)

The Flashmovie works with Actionscript 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a look at the documentation for ExternalInterface, which provides the link between JavaScript and Flash in a webpage.

The basics run along the lines of importing the library in Flash:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
```

Then you can bind a routine to be called from Javascript by using `addCallback()`:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback('stopVideo', stopVideo);

function stopVideo() {
   ...
}
```

That provides a function called `stopVideo()` on the flash object on the webpage.

And you can call a Javascript function from Flash by using `call()`:

```
ExternalInterface.call('updatePlayerInfo', "STOPPED");
```

That calls a Javascript routine called `updatePlayerInfo()` with the argument `'STOPPED'`.

The [AS3 documentation for ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) is much the same as AS2, I can not seem to locate the AS2 documentation at present.

Answer (score 1):

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

external interface will assist you in this. above you'll find the adobe reference, below many questions on the subject. this is the same for AS2/AS3

[ExternalInterface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736212/externalinterface)

[Pass a callback in ExternalInterface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802638/pass-a-callback-in-externalinterface)

[jQuery(this) and ExternalInterface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189442/jquerythis-and-externalinterface)

[Is there a way to call a Javascript class method from ExternalInterface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353188/is-there-a-way-to-call-a-javarscipt-class-method-from-externalinterface)

[How to expose the JavaScript interface for an embedded Flash object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343687/how-to-expose-the-javascript-interface-for-an-embedded-flash-object)

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful to standardize how you get reference to the running swf for invoking your callbacks:
[jQuery SWFObject Plugin](http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/)